# How do i find suitable power source given component specs

Tags: batteries, motor, amperage

If i am aware of the specs of electrical components in a project like for example in mine i am using 4 dc motors with the following specs for each:

1. Operating Voltage Range: 3~7.5V
2. Rated Voltage: 6V
3. Max. No-load Current(3V): 140 mA
4. Max. No-load Current(6V): 170 mA
5. No-load Speed(3V): 90 rpm
6. No-load Speed(6V): 160 rpm
7. Max. Output Torque: 0.8 kgf.cm
8. Max. Stall Current: 2.8 A

based on this information how would i calculate or find a suitable battery capacity or amphour delivery to power the four motors?
What i mean is how would calculate the specs of a suitable battery that i can use.

Comment: 2 LiPo in series (2S1P) gives 7.4 to 6V depending on quality  1.5Ah to 3Ah typ Start current is 2.8A/motor so discharge time is short so get array of 2S4P using (8) cells for more energy. Consider  8A PTC per string for protection.

Comment: Does the battery pack have to be remove to charge? What is the max weight you allow for the batt? What capacity you're looking at?

Comment: 4xAA battery. seems like a good starting point,

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider the operate time and the normal run loading.

If the life time is short.
2 LiPo in series is OK.
Start current = 2.8*4 = 11.2A is quite large?
18650 Lipo can support 20A.

2 Lipo in series supply max 8.4V which is over the operate voltage?
Use PWM to drive.